# Are there software for drawing Feynman diagrams easily?

Tags: resource-recommendations, feynman-diagrams, software

I want to know if there softwares to draw Feynman diagrams easily.

Comment: [Answering in comments](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/966/9887) - *"Whenever you see someone post something as a comment that seems like it should be an answer, ask them to make it an answer."*

Comment: Thanks Alfred! I've deleted the comments posted which were attempting to answer the question (and your replies, since they're no longer needed after the original comments were deleted). On another note, according to meta software recommendation questions are generally disallowed but [with an exception for software that is specific to physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2907/124). I think this question is borderline according to that criterion, but I'm not going to unilaterally vote to close it.

Comment: @DavidZ I think the question is misunderstood: the existing answer deals with the graphical software, whereas the question is mor elikely about drawing all the diagrams up to a particular order in the Feynmann-Dyson expansion.

Comment: @Vadim I see no evidence to suggest whether that's the case. We would need to hear it from the OP. I've reverted your edit because I believe it adds extra information into the question and possibly changes its meaning.

Comment: @DavidZ So you acknowledge that the question allows several interpretations. Yet, the moderator forced closure without attempting to clarify the meaning.